# convert php array to array

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say I'm having the following php array

```
Array(
[0]=>a,b,c
)
```

how can I convert it to get as result another array, what should look like

```
Array(

[0]=>a

[1]=>b

[2]=>c
)
```

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/explode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple use php explode() function for that.`explode(",", $somearray[0]);`.

Answer (score 4):

```
// $a = array('a,b,c');
$b = explode(',', $a[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to create index array if you want to give first index of your array whatever you want rather than 0.

```
Array(
[0]=>'a','b','c'
)
```

So if you want to start you first index from 10 than.

```
 Array(
   [10]=>'a','b','c'
 )
```

will result like this

```
 Array(
    [10]=>'a',
    [11]=>'b',
    [12]=>'c'
    )
```